# popup form dropdownlist change function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created a list view CRUD edit program. In the list view, when a user clicks on the Edit button a popup form will be shown. This works.

On popup of the form I have a Product dropdown list and I get this list function well. However when I tried to use the Product dropdown list's value it does not work.

I need some help or tutorial for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ProductId").change(function() {
    $.get("/controller/action", {
      p1: $("#ProductId").val()
    }, function(data) {
    });
  });
});
```

I am working in ASP.Net MVC using Visual Studio 2017 express

Comment: If the popup is dynamically created it sounds like you need to use a delegated event handler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Here you have my answer which i did answer recently https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071480/10750663

Comment: please add code in your view and your script here

Comment: thanks , Hien Nguyen , but there are only 600 characters allowed ,so i am asking a new question with my full code and my exception